# Excel shortcut X amount of cells

Tags: excel, shortcut

Is there a way to move X amount of cells with a shortcut?

Example, I would like to move 50 rows down from my position without counting.

Comment: Well, that will take vba.

Comment: There isn't a shortcut where I press ctrl + shift + down arrow + 9 to move down 9 cells?

Comment: no there is not.  Just an FYI a question of this nature, where you are trying to find if some functionality exists in a program, should be asked on [SuperUser].  This site is for code problems.

Comment: Outside of VBA, best I can come up with is F5 to bring up the GoTo window and you can specify which cell to go to (i.e.: type in F109 to go directly to that cell)

Comment: Thanks you all. Okay thought this was a site to ask questions about technology. My apologizes